# Solving an ODE with a piecewise coefficient

Tags: matlab, ode

I have to plot on the whole interval `[0,500]` the solution of the second order ODE `y''(x)+f(x)y(x)+y(x)=0`, with the initial condition `y(0)=0.1`, `y'(0)=0.1`, where `f : [0,500] -> [0,1]`,

[image]

I used the function

```
function dwdt=equat(t,w)
f = @(x) zeros(size(x));
for i= 2:500
    Bounds_1 = [i - (1/i^2),i];
    Bounds_2 = [i,i + (1/i^2)];
    f1 = @(x) (i^2.*x - i^3 + 1).*(Bounds_1(1) < x & x <= Bounds_1(2));
    f2 = @(x) (-i^2.*x + i^3 + 1).*(Bounds_2(1) < x & x <= Bounds_2(2));
    f = @(x) f(x) + f1(x) + f2(x); 
end
dwdt=zeros(2,1);
dwdt(1)=w(2);
dwdt(2)=-f*w(2)-w(1);
end
```

With the commands

```
tspan = [0 500];
z0=[0.1 0.1];
[t,z] = ode45(@(t,z) equat(t,z), tspan, z0);
figure
plot(t,z(:,1),'r');
```

I get several errors

```
Unary operator '-' is not supported for operand of type 'function_handle'.

Error in equat (line 12)
dwdt(2)=-f*w(2)-w(1);

Error in @(t,z)equat(t,z)

Error in odearguments (line 90)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.

Error in ode45 (line 115)
  odearguments(FcnHandlesUsed, solver_name, ode, tspan, y0, options, varargin);
```

How could I fixed it, to obtain the plotting of the solution `y(x)`?

LE: The plotting of the solution with the functions suggested by Lutz: [image]

Comment: You've got some extensive recursion going on by redifining `f` as a function in terms of itself within that loop, I don't think that can be intentional! The error is pretty clear, you are trying to subtract a value from a function handle which isn't defined, please debug your code and look how `f` changes, perhaps you actually hoped to assign the output of `f` to an array, rather than overwriting `f` with a different function at each step?

Answer (score 1):

So you have "hats" or triangular spikes at position `i` with radius `1/i^2`. As they do not overlap for `i>=2`, only one is active, non-zero. Thus you can compute

```
i = round(x); i = max(2,min(500,i));
fx = max(0,1-i*i*abs(x-i));
```

This is not realizable without extensive contortions via anonymous functions, but you can include it directly into the ODE system function or declare it as a normal function.

```
function fx = f(x)
  i = max(2,min(500,round(x)));
  fx = max(0,1-i*i*abs(x-i));
end%function

function dwdt=equat(x,w)
  dwdt = zeros(2,1);
  dwdt(1) = w(2);
  dwdt(2) = -f(x)*w(2)-w(1);
end%function
```

You may observe that the later, very thin spikes may be jumped over by the integrator. Set the error tolerances more strictly, set a maximum step size (this may be very uneconomical) or split the piecewise linear function up in segments where it is linear, as it is given, and use `odextend` to splice the pieces together.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. So, I used the functions you wrote `f` and `equat` and I obtained with the commands `tspan = [0 500];
z0=[0.1 0.1];
[t,z] = ode45(@(t,z) equat(t,z), tspan, z0);
figure
plot(t,z(:,1),'r');` the plotting on [0,500] that I added as image in the Question.

Comment: I wonder if can it be considered correct. It seems very difficult to me the using of `odextend`.

Comment: I think this will be hard to see. The system is a standard harmonic oscillator where in regular steps the "braking pedal" is applied, for rapidly decreasing interval lengths. So one would expect a decline in amplitude, but with a slope that becomes rapidly almost horizontal. The plot looks somewhat like that, a closer examination of the extrema might confirm the declining amplitude. `dE/dt = -c*E/t^2` gives `E=E_inf*exp(c/t)` for `E=(x'^2+x^2)/2`